# CAPTCHA plugin where I can use my own images and ask my own questions?

Tags: plugin-recommendation, plugins, spam, captcha

Just wondering if any of you have run across this kind of plugin.

Basically I'd like to be able to (a) specify my own image; (b) specify my own challenge question; (c) specify my own answer.  As in:

(a) an image of the word "orange" written in Old English
(b) "Type the word you see in the picture"
(c) the answer is "orange"

Does such a plugin exist?  Thanks!

Comment: Might want to consider a PHP captcha script, yes you'd have to port it into plugin form(or maybe just write a bit of code to intergrate it), but it would open up the possibilities a great deal. This one apparently provides lots of customization: http://www.phpcaptcha.org/ ... you may also wish to check out some of the others listed here: http://www.hotscripts.com/category/php/scripts-programs/security-systems/captcha-scripts/

Answer (score 1):

I can not recommend you one that does this, but you can review all captcha plugins on worpdress org regarding your needs and then report back which did this or at least partially.

Perform an optimized search

Comment: Thanks for the "custom" adjective.  I hadn't tried that yet.

Comment: @John: oh that's cool feedback. I just have learned the last days that site: accepts subdirectories within URLs for google search. But I smell that such a plugin does not exists so far, right? Let me know if there is anything close to your needs at last. I like what you ask for.

Answer (score 1):

## Update:   From my hard-earned painful expereince, [KeyCAPTCHA is scam by professional spammers](http://keycaptchaured.wordpress.com)

---

You can create your own captchas from your own images with "Personal Captcha" of KeyCAPTCHA

- https://www.keycaptcha.com/whatisit/?s=pc

For subscribers of such service there is online designer

The basic service is free but possibility of creating your own captchas is fee-based (5 USD a months, 20 a year)